# Android Java - How to remove image noise in faster way?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, noise-reduction

I have these code to reduce image noise:

```
for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
        // get one pixel color
        int pixel = processedBitmap.getPixel(x, y);

        // retrieve color of RGB
        int R = Color.red(pixel);
        int G = Color.green(pixel);
        int B = Color.blue(pixel);

        // convert into single value
        R = G = B = (int) (0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B);

        // convert to black and white + remove noise
        if (R > 162 && G > 162 && B > 162)
            bitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.WHITE);
        else if (R < 162 && G < 162 && B < 162)
            bitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

But the time takes very long to generate the outcome. Is there any other way to optimize these code to make it faster?

Comment: that probably is the fastest way in Java. You will have to write in using NDK to work faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use getPixel.  Get the image data as an array and use math to access the correct pixel.  Write the math such that the fewest multiplications possible are used.  Same for setPixel.

Don't use Color.red(), Color.green(), etc.  Use masking, its more efficient than a function call.

Even better, drop into the NDK and do this in C.  Image manipulation in Java is generally less than optimal.